# HTML canvas proxy getContext issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, proxy

In a javascript userscript for a website having a canvas with the id of "canvas", I use the following code using unsafeWindow to make a proxy of that canvas:

```
const proxy = new Proxy(unsafeWindow.HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext, {
    apply(target, thisArg, args) {
        const ctx = Reflect.apply(...arguments);

        const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(ctx);
        const descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(prototype);

        Object.defineProperties(prototype, {
            arc: {
                value(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {
                        const { a, b, c, d, e, f } = ctx.getTransform();
                        const scale = 2;
                        ctx.setTransform(a * scale, b, c, d * scale, e, f);

                    return descriptors.arc.value.call(this, ...arguments);
                }
            },
        });

        return ctx;
    }
});
unsafeWindow.HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = proxy;
```

but everytime in that script I call the canvas like `const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');`, it calls the proxy so for example here, for the arc proprety, the scale is applied one more time each time I call `document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d')`, does anyone knows a way to call `document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d')` without it calling the proxy?

Comment: This is interesting stuff... TIL Proxy is a thing. Could you store a reference to the canvas 2d context before Proxy uses the getContext method as its target?

Answer (score 0):

solved,
use that:

```
const proxy = new Proxy(unsafeWindow.OffscreenCanvas.prototype.getContext, {
    set: (target, key, value) => {
        return true;
    },
    get: (target, key) => {
        if (key !== "__isProxy") {
            return target[key];
        }

        return true;
    },
    apply(target, thisArg, args) {
        if (args[0] === 'noProxy') return Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, args.slice(1));
        const ctx = Reflect.apply(...arguments);

        const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(ctx);
        const descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(prototype);

        Object.defineProperties(prototype, {
            arc: {
                value(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {
                        const { a, b, c, d, e, f } = ctx.getTransform();
                        const scale = 2;
                        ctx.setTransform(a * scale, b, c, d * scale, e, f);

                    return descriptors.arc.value.call(this, ...arguments);
                }
            },
        });

        return ctx;
    }
});
unsafeWindow.OffscreenCanvas.prototype.getContext = proxy;
```

and call the canvas with that:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('noProxy', '2d');
```